# How to use numpy.where to change all pixels of an image?

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing

I have an image of shape (300,300,3) consisting of these pixels `[255, 194, 7],[224, 255, 8],[230, 230, 230],[11, 102, 255]`. I want to change this pixel `[230, 230, 230]` to `[255,255,255]`. And rest other pixels to `[0,0,0]`. So I'm applying numpy `where` function to switch the pixels. Below is the code:

```
import numpy

im = numpy.array([[[255, 194, 7],[224, 255, 8],[230, 230, 230],[11, 102, 255]]])

im[np.where((im == [230, 230, 230]).all(axis = 2))] = [255,255,255]
im[np.where((im != [255,255,255]).all(axis = 2))] = [0,0,0]
```

The first code is working fine, but all the pixels that have `255` in it like `[11, 102, 255]` doesnot get flipped at all in the second line. and the image remains same. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What is `im`? Show us how it is *made*. Is it a PIL Image, or a Pillow Image or a .....? Also it would help if you could show us a 5x5x3 example and the expected result. [mcve]

Comment: Wouldn't you be better using 8-bit unsigned data type?

Comment: Change `all` to `any` on the last line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
im = np.array([[[255, 194, 7],[224, 255, 8],[230, 230, 230],[11, 102, 255]]])
```

Like this?
Make a mask and use it to change the values.

```
>>> mask = im == 230
>>> im[mask] = 255
>>> im[np.logical_not(mask)] = 0

>>> im
=> array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0]]])
```

Or using numpy.where

```
>>> np.where(im==230, 255, 0)

=> array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
np.array_equal(arr1, arr2)
```